# I got the following error : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data' can you help please

Tags: pandas

I do have the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'`

appreciate your input

````
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from IPython.display import SVG
from graphviz import Source
from IPython.display import display                               
from ipywidgets import interactive
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/dean/Desktop/AI TECNOMATIX EXCEL/cartest1.csv")
#print(df1)
inputs = df1.drop('StatNumOut',axis='columns')
target = df1['StatNumOut']
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le_company = LabelEncoder()
le_job = LabelEncoder()
le_degree = LabelEncoder()
inputs['name_n'] = le_company.fit_transform(inputs['name'])
inputs['MachineAvailability_n'] = le_company.fit_transform(inputs['MachineAvailability'])
inputs['MachineExitLocked_n'] = le_job.fit_transform(
    inputs['MachineExitLocked'])
inputs['MachineEntranceLocked_n'] = le_degree.fit_transform(
    inputs['MachineEntranceLocked'])
inputs['MachineMTTR_n'] = le_degree.fit_transform(inputs['MachineMTTR'])
inputs['StatNumIn_n'] = le_degree.fit_transform(inputs['StatNumIn'])
inputs_n = inputs.drop(['name',
                        'MachineAvailability',
                        'MachineEntranceLocked',
                        'MachineExitLocked',
                        'MachineMTTR',
                        'StatNumIn'],
                       axis='columns')
inputs_n
target

model.score(inputs_n,target)

labels = df1.feature_names
def plot_tree(crit, split, depth, min_split, min_leaf=0.2):
    estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0 
       , criterion = crit
       , splitter = split
       , max_depth = depth
       , min_samples_split=min_split
       , min_samples_leaf=min_leaf)
    estimator.fit(inputs_n, target)
    graph = Source(tree.export_graphviz(estimator
       , out_file=None
       , feature_names=labels
       , class_names=['0', '1', '2']
       , filled = True))

    display(SVG(graph.pipe(format='svg')))
    return estimator

inter=interactive(plot_tree,
                  crit = ["gini", "entropy"],
                  split = ["best", "random"],
                  depth=[1,2,3,4],
                  min_split=(0.1,1),
                  min_leaf=(0.1,0.5))
display(inter)
```
````

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-da5106eae202> in <module>
      1 # class labels
      2 
----> 3 labels = df1.feature_names


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'

Comment: Can you add a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Its df1.columns

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the error message, a `pandas.DataFrame` object has no attribute named `feature names`. You probably meant something like `df1.columns`.

Comment: Thank you for your response I have changed it and it worked. I just got this error now which is regarding the input number of input in feature name.  I am new to programing and any help is appreciated thanks.    ValueError: Length of feature_names, 7 does not match number of features, 6

Comment: It is likely that `df1` contains the features *and* the target variable, while the `feature_names` parameters accepts only the list of features. Try `feature_names=labels[:-1]`